# US VAT refund, can it be claimed at a later date?

Tags: united-states, vat, refund

I was in NY recently,about 3 weeks ago and purchased a Macbook Pro from the Apple Store. I was unaware that I could claim a tax refund at the airport so didn't claim it as yet.

I do have my receipt and will be in NY in 6 weeks again .

My question is, if I go back to the Apple store with my receipt and passport will they be able to stamp it for a refund and can I claim it at the airport on my return to my home country a week later end September? Also do I need to have that laptop with me at the time?

Answer (score 7):

There's no VAT in the US. What you paid was "[sales tax](http://www.economywatch.com/business-and-economy/difference-between-value-added-tax-and-sales-tax.html)". It is not refundable to foreigners. You were unaware that you could claim it at the airport - because you couldn't, cannot and will not be able even if you come back to the store with your foreign passport. The State of New York doesn't issue such refunds.